# Django dev server not recognizing new files after directory modification

Tags: django

I have a Django project with 2 apps and was writing some functions in a utils.py file in one of the apps. I wanted to break this up into two separate files in their own subdirectory so I created a new directory 'utils' a level below the app directory and placed the two utils1.py and utils2.py files in there.

I had some issues with importing something from the other app so I ended up scrapping this idea and moving everything back into one file in the base directory of the original app, exactly like it was before. Now when I runserver it is not picking up any new files that are created within apps. Not just the ones that I recreated but any new files. Files that were created prior to the change are running just fine.

So, in summary new utils.py files that I recreated in the app directory are not running when the dev server is started, and when I try to run one of them manually they run like any other python file, but imports from other locations in the project are not being recognized.

No other changes were made and new files were running perfectly fine before the directory changes.

After the changes:

```
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── permissions.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── app2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── utilities        <--- added
        ├── util1.py
        └── util2.py
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── serializers.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

After reverting back to previous structure (not working):

```
├── app1               <--- new files created here aren't running
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── permissions.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── app2                <--- new files created here aren't running
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── util1.py        <--- moved back into app directory
    ├── migrations
    ├── models.py
    ├── util2.py        <--- moved back into app directory
    ├── serializers.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

I've tried clearing the pycache files, restarting the dev server, restarting terminal, etc. to no avail.

Comment: I didn't make any changes to models so there were no migrations to apply

Comment: I also tried cloning a previous commit and the issue persists, and checked if any other rouge runserver processes were running but didn't seem like it

Comment: Also worth noting that I just checked and this is happening for all my projects. Different virtual env for each project, same local environment.

Comment: what util1.py and util2.py does. Can you post the content of these files to get the idea?

Comment: No matter the contents of the files they aren't recognized by the dev server. Even if they just contain print('hello world') that won't show up in the terminal when I runserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. My assumption was that any new python files in an installed app would be automatically run, but something from the file needs to be imported first from somewhere else in the project. Before the changes I had an import in the utils.py file so the dev server was running it, but after the changes there were no imports from elsewhere in the project. Issue is fixed and working now.